# virtualenv + setuptools issue in Pyramid

Tags: python, web, virtualenv, pyramid, setuptools

I have followed [these instructions](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/project.html). That is:

- Created a folder `blah_project` and another folder `venv` within it.
- Run `virtualenv --no-site-packages venv` to create a virtual environment inside `venv`.
- Activated `venv` with `source venv/bin/activate`
- Run `pip install pyramid`
- Run `pcreate -s alchemy blah`

Now, the problem I'm facing is that if I run any command, for instance `python blah/setup.py test -q`, the required packages are installed not in the appropriate `venv` subpath, but rather in the current directory. Is that the expected behaviour? How do I setup the script to always install packages in the right path?

I tried looking inside `setup.py` and I don't really find anything relevant, i.e. there is no path passed on to `setuptools.setup()` function call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
pip install -e .
```

That will help you to install the requirements in your venv environment.

Comment: I found the same thing somewhere in the official docs and it works.

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behavior with the `test` subcommand of setup.py unfortunately. The way we solve this in a lot of our subprojects is by defining a new alias called `setup.py dev` which installs both testing dependencies and actual dependencies at the same time. However I don't have a great solution for you as this is the way `setup.py test` works intentionally. Below are links to the Pyramid configuration that allows `setup.py dev` to work.

https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blob/master/setup.cfg#L12

https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blob/master/setup.py#L99